# Split a float number at decimal point using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to split a number at the decimal point and store the two parts in two strings.

E.g. 12.345 to be stored as S1 = 12 and S2 = 345

E.g. 12.3450 to be stored as S1 = 12 and S2 = 345

Can someone guide me with excel VBA for this?

Comment: why vba, a simple formula would do it: s1 `=INT(12.345)` and S2 `=MOD(12.345,1)`

Comment: @ScottCraner S2 would give .345 rather than 345

Comment: @ScottCraner Dodgy quick fix for cell S2: =ROUND(MOD(12.345, 1), 10)*10^(LEN(ROUND(MOD(12.345, 1), 10))-2)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the split function to do this:

```
Dim splitnnum
Dim num as Double

num = 111.222
splitnum = Split(Str(num), ".")
s1 = splitnum(0)
s2 = splitnum(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This will split at the decimal and assign each part to a string.

```
Dim x as Variant
Dim num1 as String, num2 as String

x = Split(Str(12.345), ".")
num1 = x(Lbound(x,1))
num2 = x(Ubound(x,1))
```

Comment: I like this answer but I'm not sure that LBound and Ubound are really necessary in this context

Comment: Necessary, not at all, but I rather like not specifying specific indexes. Call it stylistic preference.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it would likely be something like:

```
Dim lHolder as Double
Dim lWhole as Double
Dim lRemain as Double

lHolder = 12.345 ' Or whatever variable you have your number stored in
lWhole = Fix(lHolder)
lRemain = lHolder - lWhole
```

You can then round lRemain as needed. For example

```
Round(lRemain, 5) ' Rounds out to 5 decimal places
```

Will return .345

Answer (score 0):

This breaks your number at decimal point

mynumber = 111.222

splitmynumber  = Split(Str(mynumber ), ".")

'This is an array storing 2 number

numberbeforedecimal = val(splitmynumber  (0))

numberafterdecimal = val(splitmynumber  (1))

Answer : 111 & 222